# Was the "Something Wicked This Way Comes" tag line to the Prisoner Of Azkaban movie poster taken from the 1962 Ray Bradbury novel of the same name?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, ray-bradbury, advertisements

I remember seeing this *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban* poster when I was younger and thinking that the "Something Wicked This Way Comes" tag line was very catchy and incredibly clever. I was always somewhat mildly curious how they came up with the line:

[image: Prisoner Of Azkaban Movie Poster]

However I've most recently today just happened upon this Wikipedia article on a 1962 novel by Ray Bradbury with the same name: [*Something Wicked This Way Comes* (novel)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_Wicked_This_Way_Comes_(novel)).

[image: Ray Bradbury Novel]

I was wondering if the tag line may have been borrowed from the novel or where it might have originally come from. I know many people in art and music can borrow from one another, and I was wondering whether this same line was independently created or taken from a previous source of inspiration such as the Ray Bradbury novel.

Comment: I put a lot of clarification of what I meant in the question body itself. I have also changed the title to taken and hope that suits you better.

Comment: If I'd downvote this, I'd downvote for the reason that the origin is mentioned on the very page the OP links to.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking -- what seemed "incredibly clever" about the tagline? (For me it resonates only because of the *Macbeth* allusion; I wouldn't have thought it would even stand out to someone who didn't recognize it.)

Comment: How they came up with it?  Stole it from Will Shakespeare, that's how.  If you're going to steal, you might as well steal from the best :-)  (See also Agatha Christie's "By the Pricking of My Thumbs")

Comment: @jamesqf *Also* see also Dr. Seuss' classic work "Open, locks, Whoever knocks"

Comment: Going along with @ruakh : If you think *this* is "incredibly clever", you're going to be blown away by Shakespeare's best lines; this probably isn't in the top 1000.

Comment: It's really hard to place why I thought it was clever. It was over 10 years ago I saw the poster, and I feel like the thought itself was subconscious and it just "felt" deeper than I would expect in a movie poster. If I had to try to express it as logic and this may just be guessing, it was unusual to see extra effort to twist words around in an unconventional way instead of just putting "Something wicked comes this way". It would take thinking in a special way, and persistence through a lot of editors and team members who would question the wording and want to "fix" it.

Comment: @azoundria: I would think anyone who knows enough English to be an editor would be familiar with at least the better known of Shakespeare's works.  As for the "twisted words", basically all of Shakespeare's plays are written in blank verse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blank_verse  If you read the context, or better yet listen to a good performance (I recommend the Arkangel recordings) you'll see that "twisted" or not, it all fits together.

Comment: Of course they would. That was the missing link, how that phrase could be twisted around and make it through the editing process. I knew there was an additional story. I definitely wouldn't have known it was called blank verse, but it was definitely different. How many other movie posters do you know of with something in a blank verse style? Something was different and out of place about this poster, and it piqued my interest enough that I still remember it 10 years later. Well I'm glad to have the mystery solved and thanks again!

Comment: Downvoted because even outside of this being common knowledge, a simple search of the tagline itself would have IMMEDIATELY revealed its origins. A lazy question. In fact I wish I could downvote it 40 more times.

Comment: @azoundria Missing link? Twisted around? Nothing was twisted. It is *verbatim* Shakespeare.

Comment: Firstly, I don't know what you're searching. When I look up just "Something Wicked This Way Comes" I get the Ray Bradbury novel and a movie with the same name. That being said, now that I do Ctrl + F and specifically look for Shakespeare it does show up twice in those top 100 search results, but only twice. A search like I did "Something Wicked This Way Comes" harry potter has only one mention of Shakespeare in the top 36 results - in a hashtag. Except, ironically, this question now. I think I'd much rather live in a world where you can find information quickly than one where you can't.

Comment: As for my example, I was in class, looking at the poster. I didn't have access to the internet there at that time. All I could do was use my brain, which didn't know every line of Shakespeare or what blank verse was. All I could conclude was that the poster didn't seem like a typical poster. The line didn't seem like typical English that I would expect on a movie poster. In a parallel universe where Shakespeare hadn't written that line and blank verse was never invented, I doubt that poster would ever exist in that form. Thus, Shakespeare and blank verse were the missing links to explain it.

Answer (score 124):

It's from the play *Macbeth* ([Act IV, Scene 1](https://sites.google.com/site/aesmacbeth4/act-iv-scene-1)), by William Shakespeare:

> *Second Witch: By the pricking of my thumbs, **Something wicked this way comes**. Open,
>   locks, Whoever knocks*.

Notably the line appears in the film at the end of the "Double Trouble" choir song.

Comment: And possibly worth noting that divination by recognising painful feelings, twinges and itches in the fingers and hands were an ancient Roman tradition. An itchy left palm augured the arrival of money. A pain in the finger or thumbs would foretell the arrival of evil

Comment: For those new to Shakespeare, part of the original connotation of the Shakespeare line was heavily based on the fact that the witches were overtly evil, having just before talked about using an ingredient such as "Finger of birth-strangled babe" (among a number of other unsavory items). If someone as evil as them could note that arrival of "something wicked" - Macbeth - wow, he must be a real bad dude!

Comment: The fact that it appears in a song called Double Trouble is a further Macbeth allusion.  A repeated line in the witches' chant during that scene is "Double, double toil and trouble; Fire burn, and cauldron bubble."

Comment: @BrianH:  The whole thrust of the play is about how MacBeth, who starts out as a decent, even heroic, figure, is led into evil by his own ambition after the witches tell him he is to be king.  And he even recognizes this, as he says "I am in blood Stepp'd in so far that, should I wade no more, Returning were as tedious as go o'er".

Comment: Of course you mean *the Scottish play*.

Comment: I've always preferred Shakespeare in the original Klingon.

Answer (score 25):

## It's from Macbeth.

First, i'd like to point out that the connection is made from the mention of that line: in the song [Double Trouble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMzrgXFeX_o).

> John Williams took the lyrics from the famous scene in William Shakespeare's Macbeth in which the Witches are around the cauldron and set them to music he composed for the films. One of the witches also says the phrase, "By the pricking of my thumbs, something wicked this way comes."
> <sub><sup>*- [Something Wicked This Way Comes - The Harry Potter Compendium](http://harry-potter-compendium.wikia.com/wiki/Something_Wicked_This_Way_Comes)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Althought this isn't inaccurate, it doesn't contain anything useful that isn't already in the answer above

Comment: @Valorum it contains the reference to John Williams decisionmaking.

Comment: And the fact that the entire song is a Macbeth reference, not just the final line.